# Linear Algebra Vector Tracing

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A(2,-1,1)$, $B$ and $C$ be the vertices of a triangle where $\overrightarrow{AB}$ is parallel to $\vec{v}=(2,0,-1), $$\overrightarrow{BC}$ is parallel to $\vec{w}=(1,-1,1)$ and $\angle(BAC)=90°$. Find the equation of the line through (A) and (C) in vector and parametric forms.

Well, there is not much I can do here. I could find the equation of the plane:
$-x-3y-2z=-1$ by finding the normal of the two vectors given.

Comment: I need a hint.\

Comment: Excuse, but when do you say: "the angle at (A) is a right angle" do you mean $\angle(A)=90°$?

Comment: yes exactly what is meant

Comment: @DiegoMath can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do the vector product between $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ you will obtain a vector $\vec{\eta}$ that is perpendicular to the plane generated by $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$.

Since $\angle(A)=90°$ you can imagine the vector $\vec{\eta}$ starting from $A$, then doing the product vector beween $\vec{\eta}$ and $\vec{v}$ (which is parallel to $\vec{AB}$), you will obtain a vector $\vec{\nu}$ that is perpendicular to $\vec{\eta}$ and $\vec{AB}$, since $\vec{\nu}$ lies to the plane, then $\vec{nu}$ is parallel to $\vec{AC}$.

Therefore the equation of such line in vector form is
$$\vec{X}=A+\lambda\vec{\nu}.$$

The question is done, you work is:

1) To find $\vec{\eta}$ and after that $\vec{\nu}$.

2) To write the parametric equation.

I hope this colud help you.